# Radnet challenges count for 100% unlock

Tags: prototype-2

Do the Radnet challenges count for 100% unlocks?

I want to know because I am really close to the platinum and this is my only achievement left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming by "100% unlocks", you mean "all mutations", no, the Radnet challenges do not count for mutations.

All that counts is the blacknet dossiers, lairs, blackboxes, etc.